# Changing the maximum value on an axis in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I change the max value on the axis option for Excel 2013?

Comment: Right-click on the axis for a menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

Right click on the Axis > choose "Format Axis" > choose 'Maximum' from the "Axis Options" menu and enter the 'Maximum' value you would like to apply. Screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Hope this helps.